# Aggregate by user-defined function and regression in R

Tags: r, regression, aggregate

I need to calculate the beta and the co-skewness (by using a regression) per year on a large dataset, and I have problems aggregating the dataset according to my own functions.
The dataset looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
testsample <- xts(matrix(runif(140, -1, 1), ncol=7), 
                  order.by = seq.Date(as.Date("2008-12-24"), by = "day", length.out = 20))
colnames(testsample) <- c(paste0("x", seq(from=1, to=6), ""), "RF")
```

What I have tried so far:

```
yrs <- format(index(testsample),format="%y")
Beta <- aggregate(testsample ~ yrs, testsample, 
                  function(x) CAPM.beta(Ra = x,Rb = testsample[index(x), "RF"]),
                  drop = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
COSKEW <- lapply(1:(NCOL(testsample)-1), function(x) {coef(lm(testsample[,x] ~ RF + I(RF^2), data = testsample))[3]})
```

However, for the Beta calculation, I get the following error:

> The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.

But when I try to use a data frame with named rows (with the dates as names), it still does not work. For the co-skewness, I only managed to extract the coefficient per column, but not aggregate it.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try apply.yearly

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried period.apply since my years start in may, but I still can't seem to get it right.

Comment: In that case try shifting the dates forward to the next year or backward to the beginning of the year.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Sadly, I keep getting errors.